# How can I convert Bayer/Flamsteed designations to Hipparchos numbers?

Tags: star-catalogues

In a text file I have a table of star data with Bayer/Flamsteed designations. I need to convert these into Hipparchos numbers. How can I automatically do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the names and numbers are essentially arbitrary, the Hipparcos designation cannot be calculated from the Bayer or Flamsteed designation.  Instead you have to look up the star in a database.

There is a [HD-DM-GC-HR-HIP-Bayer-Flamsteed Cross Index](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/Cat?IV/27A) on line.  ([Direct link](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/nph-Cat/txt?IV%2F27A/catalog.dat))You can get a computer to do the look up for you. Or if you only have a small number of stars, you can use SIMBAD and do the look-up by hand.

Comment: SIMBAD supports uploading a list of designations from a file and so you don't need to do it all by hand.